# How to limit google app engine instances to just one?

Tags: google-app-engine, instance, go

I'm using go language and it seems good practice to communicate between different threads/routines by channels and locks instead of datastore. However, it appears that it's not possible between two instances if there's more than one instance running. Is there a way to make it not open a second one, even if there's high traffic?

Comment: Have you tried to use memcache instead of the datastore to sync threads?

Comment: I haven't tried either one of them. I wanted to sync them with channels and locks. I guess I don't know enough about good practice in Google Go. The first thing I'll do will be learn good practices for syncing threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Backends](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/backends/overview) if you want fine to control the spawning and shutdown of instances.

Answer (score 9):

To answer the question in the title:
Go to app dashboard, on left you will find a `Application settings` link. In the admin UI you will find two sliders, drag the first one at the very left and the second (`Min pending Latency`) to the max allowed value (right). And last but not least, optimize your request response time.

Even if you do the above there's no guarantee that GAE will not fire up a second instance.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as @proppy's answer is outdated, and using deprecated technology.

Comment: Is this answer now also outdated? I no longer see the "min pending latency" slider in the application settings page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is absolutely the right approach .. You have to think about scalability issues from the first day of your design .. As christopher said I would go with memcache!

Comment: You're probably right and I'll do that. I didn't choose you as a correct answer to help googlers find the answer if they really want to control spawning and shutdown of isntances.